ERR_PNPM_BAD_PM_VERSION This project is configured to use v8.9.0 of pnpm. Your current pnpm is v9.1.1
Encountering an error related to the version of pnpm being used in a project. The error message "ERR_PNPM_BAD_PM_VERSION" indicates that the project is expecting a specific version of pnpm (v8.9.0), but your current version is different (v9.1.1).

Install the correct version of pnpm: You can try installing the specific version of pnpm that the project requires. You can do this using npm (Node Package Manager) or yarn. For example, if you're using npm, you can run:npm install -g pnpm@8.9.0

Update the project configuration: If possible, you can update the project configuration to use the current version of pnpm (v9.1.1). This might involve updating configuration files or scripts within the project.


Answer for my problem

To resolve the error "ERR_PNPM_BAD_PM_VERSION" and ensure that your project uses the specific pnpm version (v8.9.0) required, you can take one of the following approaches:
Option 1: Install the Required pnpm Version

Uninstall the current pnpm version (if necessary):
npm uninstall -g pnpm

Install the required pnpm version (v8.9.0):
npm install -g pnpm@8.9.0

Verify the installation
pnpm --version


Option 2: Use npx to Run the Specific pnpm Version Temporarily
If you don't want to globally change your pnpm version, you can use npx to run the required version temporarily for your project:
Run pnpm commands using npx:
npx -p pnpm@8.9.0 pnpm <your-command>

Replace  with the specific pnpm command you need to run, such as install, add, etc.

npx -p pnpm@x.y.z pnpm  is a nice trick for Vercel deployments -- thank you!

this doesn't work for corepack installations

Option 3: Update Project Configuration
If your project can work with the newer pnpm version (v9.1.1), you can update the project configuration to accept the current version:
Update package.json:

Activate Corepack
corepack enable
Set the Project-Specific pnpm Version
packageManager=pnpm@8.9.0
Install the Specified pnpm Version
corepack prepare pnpm@8.9.0 --activate
@GustavoOliveira You can follow these step

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
